# Why is Angualrjs not sending POST to my Express server?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I have a node Express server running on localhost that serves a page with angularjs code. When the user press a button on the page, there's an angularjs controller that post a json back to the server.

My problem is that the post doesn't seem to go to the server at all. I've checked the address and it's good. I've checked the button event and it does fire up. I'm really at a loss here. I'm new to the MEAN stack so is there something I'm doing wrong?

**The route that handles the post(routes/blogposts.js):**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var URL = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/blog';


/* POST */
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {

  process.stdout.write("hello: ");

});

module.exports = router;
```

**The angular controller that sends the post**

```
app.controller('PostController', ['$scope', function($scope) { 

   $scope.sendPost = function() {
        var id = document.getElementById("postTitle").value;
        var type = document.querySelector('input[name="postType"]:checked').value;
        var text = document.getElementById("postText").value;

        var currentDate = new Date();
        var day = currentDate.getDate();
        var month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1;
        var year = currentDate.getFullYear();
        var date = ("<b>" + day + "/" + month + "/" + year + "</b>");

        var sendObject = '{"id":' + id + ', "date": ' + date + ', "type":' + type + ', "post":' + 
                            text +'}';

        $http.post('http://localhost:3000/blogPosts', sendObject);


   };

}]);
```

EDIT: added the code to the express router below

**App.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var blogposts = require('./routes/blogposts');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/blogposts', blogposts);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

Comment: this is wrong on multiple levels. There should be no dom code in controller.  Use `ng-model` to bind form control values to data model. Creating json manually is a terrible practice (and error prone) , `$http` will automatically create it for you from data object argument

Comment: I'll keep that in mind for the future.

Comment: Post the code where the router is required in your main node app module. Also, what do you mean by App.js route localhost:3000/blogPosts calls to this angular.js stuff?

Comment: How do you know that it is not working? By "I've checked the button event", do you mean that you've verified that the `sendPost` function gets called? Have you checked your browser console for errors? Have you checked the network tab to see what is getting posted and where it gets posted to?

Comment: @RobertMoskal I meant App.js route localhost:3000/blogPosts calls to the nodejs code, not the angular stuff sorry.

Comment: @JackA. Nothing is being printed to my node console which I assume meas that no post request was received. And yes, I've checked that sendPost gets called.

Comment: @JackA. I didn't check the browser console; I'm new to this but thanks, this gave me a big clue. There is an error "$http is not defined".

Comment: Also your blogposts.js route does not end, so it'll just hang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inject `$http` into your controller like this:

```
app.controller('PostController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

The angular stuff is posting to /blogPosts and not to /.

Comment: That's fine. App.js route http://localhost:3000/blogPosts calls to this angular.js stuff. I know that works cause I actually have a get function in there that works fine but that I removed from the sample above.

Comment: I meant: calls to this "/." stuff

Answer (score 0):

following what mop said. Your angularjs controller is posting to:
$http.post('http://localhost:3000/blogPosts', sendObject);

Honestly have no idea how to read your:**The route that handles the post**
I think by showing that you make it harder to understand!.
I don't think it adds any value to the question.

your code was confusing to read so i google it.
http://expressjs.com/starter/hello-world.html

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;

  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

you would need something more like...

```
app.post('/blogPosts', function (req, res) {
      res.send('Hello World!');
    });
```

but even if you did this it still feels fishy to me.